# How to bind arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

Say i have those 3 arrays :

```
Product(milk,candy,chocolate)
Colors(white,red,black)
Rating(8,7,9)
```

How to create a loop to bind those arrays so i get 3 variables in each loop : `$product` `$color` `$rating`

So by example i will output like this:

**Milk** is **white** and has a rating of **8**/10

**Candy** is **red** and has a rating of **7**/10

**Chocolate** is **black** and has a rating of **9**/10

Thanks

Comment: ..and there's no way you can structure/retrieve it like `array( array('milk', 'white', 8), array('candy', 'red', 7), ....)` in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know if I get it right. 
But do you want something like this?

```
$products = array("milk", "candy", "chocolate");
$colors = array("white", "red", "black");
$ratings = array(8, 7, 9);

 for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($products); $i++) {
    $product = $products[$i];
    $color = $colors[$i];
    $rating = $ratings[$i];

    echo $product . ' is ' . $color . ' and has a rating of ' . $rating . '/10 <br/>';
 }
```

Output would be:

```
milk is white and has the rating of 8/10
candy is red and has the rating of 7/10
chocolate is black and has the rating of 9/10
```

Answer (score 8):

E.g. by using SPL's [MultipleIterator](http://docs.php.net/class.multipleiterator)

```
<?php
$Product=array('milk','candy','chocolate');
$Colors=array('white','red','black');
$Rating=array(8,7,9);

$it = new MultipleIterator;
$it->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($Product));
$it->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($Colors));
$it->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($Rating));

foreach( $it as $e ) {
  echo join(' - ', $e), "\n";
}
```

prints

```
milk - white - 8
candy - red - 7
chocolate - black - 9
```

Comment: Wow, never heard of MultipleIterator, I need to study the SPL library more, thanks!